# Java - Iterate an ArrayList and Find Anagrams

Tags: java, loops, linked-list, anagram

I have a list of sorted canonical words and I would like to iterate the list with an iterator to find matching canonical words which would be having same Anagrams then add them to a seperate LinkedList paired together if they match. How would I go about doing this? Would I run two iterators at once for the same list and put them in a nested while loop with one iterator on the 1st element and the second iterator inside searching the same list for all elements for match then adding it to a List if a match is found? Any ideas?

Here's what I've done so far:

Driver Class File:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Programming9Driver {

   public static void main(String[] theArgs) {
      LinkedList<Word> wordObjects = new LinkedList<Word>();
      ArrayList<String> localWords = new ArrayList<String>();
      BufferedReader localInput = null;
      BufferedWriter localOutput = null;


      try {
         String localLine;
         localInput = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words.txt"));
//         localOutput = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out9.txt"));
         while ((localLine = localInput.readLine()) != null) {
            if (localLine != "") {
            localWords.add(localLine);
            }
//          
//         
         }
/*
*/
         localInput.close();
//       localOutput.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Difficulties opening the file! " + e);
         System.exit(1);
      }

      localWords.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));
      Map<String, List<String>> anagramList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
      Iterator<String> iterAdd = localWords.iterator();

      while (iterAdd.hasNext()) {
         wordObjects.add(new Word(iterAdd.next()));   
      }
      Collections.sort(wordObjects);

      LinkedList<AnagramFamily> anagramObjects = new LinkedList<AnagramFamily>();

  }       
}
```

Word.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Word implements Comparable<Word>{

   private String myWord;

   private String myCanon;

   private Map<String, List<String>> myCanonKey = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

   public Word(final String theWord) { 
      myWord = theWord;
      myCanon = canonForm();
      myCanonKey = canonWords();    
   }

   public String canonForm() {
      String canonWord = "";
      Character[] localChars = new Character[myWord.length()];

      for (int i = 0; i < localChars.length; i++) {
         localChars[i] = myWord.charAt(i);
      }

      Arrays.sort(localChars);

      for (int i = 0; i < localChars.length; i++) {
         canonWord += localChars[i];
      }
      return canonWord;         
   }

   public Map<String, List<String>> canonWords() {
      ArrayList<String> canonList = new ArrayList<String>();
      Map<String, List<String>> canonKey = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
      canonList.add(myWord);
      canonKey.put(myCanon, canonList);
      return canonKey;
   }

   public int compareTo(Word theOther) {
      int result = canonForm().compareTo(theOther.canonForm());
      return result;
   }

   public String toString() {
      String result = "";
      result = myWord;
      if (myWord == "" || myCanon == "") {
         result = "";
      }
      return result;
   }        
}
```

How would I call from my main driver program to use the canonWords() method from the Word class java file?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already.

Comment: Posted my code I think I just need to find out how to update the Map from the original driver from the Word.java class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of going about it would be to iterate through all the strings, creating a new string from an alphabetically sorted char array of the original, and use your new string as the key in a `Map<String, List<String>>`.

**EDIT**: The code you posted seems a little over the top, to be honest. Here's a demonstration of what I had in mind:

```
Collection<LinkedList<String>> groupAnagrams(List<String> words) {
    Map<String, LinkedList<String>> anagramMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(String word : words) {
        char[] wordChars = word.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(wordChars);
        String sortedKey = new String(wordChars);
        LinkedList<String> anagramList = anagramMap.get(sortedKey);
        if(anagramList == null) {
            anagramMap.put(sortedKey, anagramList = new LinkedList<>());
        }
        anagramList.add(word);
    }
    return anagramMap.values();
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Just for fun, here's a Java 8 implementation:

```
Collection<List<String>> groupAnagrams(List<String> words) {
    return words.stream().collect(groupingBy(w -> {
                char[] chars = w.toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(chars);
                return new String(chars);
            })).values();
}
```

Comment: I tried but how would I return it to my main driver program as a call see my code for more information.